# Не пишет в базу (Python)

Tags: mysql, python, json

Подскажите, почему не получается записать(на python) в базу(mysql)
В чем ошибка ?

```
import json
import os
import sys
import mysql.connector
import datetime
from pprint import pprint


def getdata(path):
    fd = open(path)
    with fd as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    fd.close()
    return data

#не нашел подобие isset(php)
def isset(x):
    if(type(x) == None):
        return 'empty' 
    if(type(x) == bool):
        return x 
    if(len(x)== 0):
        return 'empty'
    else:   
        return x

#проверяю наличае в БД 
def check(cur ,username , channelname):
    query = ("SELECT id FROM user_data where channel_name = %s and user_id = %s" )
    cur.execute(query, (channelname, username))
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    return len(rows)

 #вставляю
def insert(cur, *data):
    ctime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
    query = ("INSERT INTO user_data (channel_name, user_id, user_first_name, user_last_name, username, type, verified, role, phone, created_at, updated_at ) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s , %s , %s , %s);" )
    cur.execute(query, (data[0], data[1], data[2], 'user_last_name','username', data[3], data[4], data[5], 'phone', ctime , ctime ))
    print(cur)
    return 0


path = sys.argv[1]
if os.path.isfile(path):
    data = getdata(path)
    channelname = path.split(".", 1)
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(
             user='homestead',
             password='secret',
             host='192.168.10.10',
             database='homestead')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    i=0;
    for d in data:
        res = check(cur ,channelname[0], d['user']['id'])
        ctime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
        if(res == 0):
                    insert(cur,
                          channelname[0],
                          d['user']['id'],          
                          isset(d['user']['first_name']),
                          isset(d['user']['type']),
                          isset(d['user']['verified']),
                          isset(d['role'])
                          )

    cur.close()
    conn.close()        
else:
    print('file not found')
```

Проверка на наличие (Select id from ..) работает, а запись в базу данных нет (def insert())
Подскажите ,правильно ли - передавать в функцию "кортеж", и есть ли другие варианты.

PS:Не нашел аналог isset функции - что-то написал.

Заранее спасибо - надеюсь на Вашу поддержку.

PS:при выполнении в консоле:

```
>>> import mysql.connector
>>> conn = mysql.connector.connect(
...          user='homestead',
...          password='secret', 
...          host='192.168.10.10',
...          database='homestead')
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> query = ("INSERT INTO user_data (channel_name, user_id, user_first_name, user_last_name, username, type, verified, role, phone, created_at, updated_at ) VALUES ('test', '656586560', 'add','add', 'name', 'type', 1,'sjjs' ,phone , null , null);")
>>> curs = cur.execute(query)
>>>
```

не получаю ошибок, и в базу запись не идет.

В mysql данный запрос проходит

```
mysql> INSERT INTO user_data (channel_name, user_id, user_first_name, user_last_name, username, type, verified, role, phone, created_at, updated_at ) VALUES ('test2', '656586560', 'add','add', 'name', 'user_datatype', 1,'type' ,'phone' , null , null);
```

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

Предварительно извеняюсь - вчера только начал ковырять python ...

Comment: Вы бы эта... предусмотрели вывод сообщений сервера. Потому как если он при попытке вставить данные сообщает об ошибке, Вы этого не видите.

Comment: я поудалял все print() для читабельности ..
дело в том что, функция insert не возвращает ошибок (

Comment: Вот даже отсюда видно, что в поле `\`phone\`` вносится непонятное `phone` - тогда как туда, наверное, необходимо подставить значение соответствующей переменной...

Comment: в бд string указан для поля phone - так что без разницы.

Comment: Не-а... Вы передаёте не литерал `'phone'`, который мог бы лечь в поле строкового типа, а некий токен `phone`, про который MySQL знать не знает. Он будет полагать, что это имя поля, но т.к. у запроса нет таблицы-источника, будет ошибка. Не поленитесь выполнить на консоли сервера запрос в точности в той форме, в которой Вы его видите в уже удалённом из комментариев логе - сервер Вам сообщит, что он не понимает, откуда брать поле `phone`.

Comment: так там именно строка , а не токен (я пробовал - передавать данные в "ассоциативном массиве" -  насколько понял -  в python такого нет )) 
возможно чего-то не понимаю - только вчера начал ковырять python
 (да и тут явно указатель на con  в фунцию не передается )
Подскажите как правильно )) - заранее спасибо ))

Comment: *так там именно строка* **НЕТ**. Вот будь в коде кавычки (такие же, как в *В mysql данный запрос проходит*) - тогда да. Но в питоновском коде этих одинарных кавычек вокруг токена `phone` в секции `VALUES` - нету. Включите General Log и убедитесь, что на сервер приходит вовсе не то. что Вы пробуете на консоли.

Comment: попробуйте еще раз в консоли, но закройте курсор и подключение после вставки.

Comment: я не могу утверждать, что это сработает, но попробуйте убрать звездочку в data при объявлении функции и передавать данные обычным списком, или на крайний случай словарём

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, нет вызова `commit()`, поэтому в базу ничего не попадает.

P.S. Пишите сначала примерчик на 5-10 строчек...

Comment: Спасибо - после добавления conn.commit() заработало на тестовом примерчике .. 
еще тут явно ошибка в передаче указателя (cursor) в функцию)) 
Спасибо